# Send Global keystroke using JavaScript in FireFox/Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey, mouseevent

I currently have a GM script that captures a keystroke and programmatically clicks an element on a webpage. However, this only works when the page/tab has focus. Is there any way to capture the keystroke from the second page/tab and apply the click to an element on the first page/tab? I know I can get a reference to another window by opening it in JavaScript. However, I can't access elements in that window if it is on another domain. If I cannot do this using Greasemonkey, any suggestions on how to accomplish it as an extension instead of a GM script. Really, this question is more how to get a reference to an open tab/window in a GM script, or as an extension.

Here is the sample code I'm working with:

```
function dispatchMouseEvent(target, event) {

  var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  e.initMouseEvent(event, true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);  
  target.dispatchEvent(e);

};

function mouseClick(element) {

    dispatchMouseEvent(element, 'mouseover');
    dispatchMouseEvent(element, 'mousedown');
    dispatchMouseEvent(element, 'click');
    dispatchMouseEvent(element, 'mouseup');
}
```

Comment: This cannot be done in JS or GreaseMonkey, by design.  It used to be a huge security hole.  You'll have to write an extension (add-on).

Comment: I was worried this may be the case. I suppose, I'll have to read up on extensions and start there. If you post an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done in JS or Greasemonkey, by design. It used to be a huge security hole. You'll have to write an extension (add-on).

Here are some add-on resources, I've found helpful:

- [Mozilla extensions home page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions)
- [Add-on Builder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/tools/builder)
- [10 Things They Never Tell You In Firefox Extension School](http://www.sitepoint.com/ten-tips-firefox-extensions/)
- [Developing Firefox Extensions – Paper](http://www.disenchant.ch/blog/developing-firefox-extensions-paper/96)

Answer (score 0):

Can you precede your GreaseMonkey script with a javascript call to `window.focus()`?

Comment: That would just focus the current window, not the one containing the page I want to interact with.

Comment: @Chris Hendry: I meant, use javascript to get a reference to the window you want to interact with, and call myOtherWindow.focus()