# Getting a greasemonkey script to interact with a running process?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Say I have a local daemon running on my machine, and I want to talk to the daemon from a **Greasemonkey** script. I know that one of the core concepts of site JavaScript is that it is isolated from everything else, but I was wondering if there was a workaround.

One of the ideas I had was to use a WebSocket to send data to the local daemon but they are only available on Webkit based browsers.

Comment: What about [`GM_xmlhttpRequest`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/index.php?title=GM_xmlhttpRequest&oldid=6445)?

Comment: I'd probably need the daemon to run an HTTP server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three possibilities:

1. Give the daemon web-server capabilities and then use normal AJAX techniques via `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` to interact with it.
2. Instead of a GM script, [make a Firefox add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474455/send-global-keystroke-using-javascript-in-firefox-greasemonkey/6474594#6474594).  Add-ons can interact with the local system in much more dangerous ways than a GM script can.
3. I do not recommend this last approach, but include it for completeness... It may be possible for the daemon to read and/or write Firefox cookies or localStorage.  GM scripts can also, but XSS restrictions apply here (unlike with `GM_xmlhttpRequest()`).

Answer (score 1):

You could get the daemon to accept HTTP requests, which are done very easily using JavaScript? I think you are going to need to improve the daemon here, rather than the script itself - JavaScript is very secure, and Greasemonkey just takes that a step further.

Comment: Essentially correct, but ordinary JS does not make XSS HTTP requests easily.  Consider mentioning `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` in your answer.

Comment: Very good point. The reason I didn't mention this is because this isn't supported by userscripts in Chrome. Your answer has mentioned it though, so I'll leave this one as is.

Comment: I don't think you can do XSS requests in Chrome userscripts, Unless that's changed in the last few months.

Comment: As far as I'm aware (no time to test it), you can do it using Cross Origin Resource Sharing http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/